# Использование хэш-суммы sha256 двоичного числа для создание сид фразы на python

Tags: хеширование, криптография, sha256, hashlib, seed

Для генерации сида (12 слов) надо взять хэш (sha256) 128-битного бинарного числа, но тут оно воспринимается как текст. Поэтому итоговая хэш сумма не та, что мне нужна. Как реализовать это на питоне? Например, хэш 101 как текста это 16dc368a89b428b2485484313ba67a3912ca03f2b2b42429174a4f8b3dc84e44. Но значение хэша для 101 как битовой величины это c19a797fa1fd590cd2e5b42d1cf5f246e29b91684e2f87404b81dc345c7a56a0, именно это значение мне и нужно получить с помощью кода.

```
import hashlib
def calculate_sha256_binary(binary_number):
    binary_string = str(binary_number)
    byte_data = binary_string.encode()
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(byte_data).hexdigest()
    return sha256_hash
print(calculate_sha256_binary((101)))
```

Увидеть это можно тут: https://cryptii.com : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если число в виде строки в "x" то в общем виде `x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')`. только если число больше 255 то надо правильно указать порядок байтов во втором параметре. кроме того решить действительно ли оно в байтах должно быть минимально возможной длины (как в этом примере) или может его надо до определенного кол-ва байт дополнить нулями

Comment: @Mike , если число в виде строки, то выдает ошибку:`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'`. Если же в в виде целого, то хэш меняется, но верным не становится.                    `import hashlib
def calculate_sha256_binary(binary_number):
    binary_string = str(binary_number)
    byte_data = binary_string.encode()
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(byte_data).hexdigest()
    return sha256_hash
x=101
x=x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
print(calculate_sha256_binary(x)) #17eb90aab6b1f4069db2d6c7a0f02963843a60faf0eaa3ce3bd286c2373cf4b7`

Comment: А, точно, сначала в int его переведите x = int(x)

Comment: Ну результат, как я и написал, все еще не верный. на 101 выдает 17eb90aab6b1f4069db2d6c7a0f02963843a60faf0eaa3ce3bd286c2373cf4b7, а надо c19a797fa1fd590cd2e5b42d1cf5f246e29b91684e2f87404b81dc345c7a56a0

Comment: Так, стоп, а 101 это в какой системе счисления ? Случайно не в двоичной ? тогда может `x = int('101', 2)` ?

Comment: Еще один неверный результат. https://cryptii.com/ тут при указанных мной настройках получается то хэш, который нужен. Если же на вход указать текст, а не биты, то получится мой изначальный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего хочу уточнить один момент, многие могли подумать что `101` это `5` но, проведя экперимент с онлайн калькулятором я выяснил что это `160` т.е:

```
0b10100000
```

Далее обратившись к [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) я нашел пример использования библиотеки:

> ```
> import hashlib
> m = hashlib.sha256()
> m.update(b"Nobody inspects")
> m.update(b" the spammish repetition")
> m.digest()
> b'\x03\x1e\xdd}Ae\x15\x93\xc5\xfe\\\x00o\xa5u+7\xfd\xdf\xf7\xbcN\x84:\xa6\xaf\x0c\x95\x0fK\x94\x06'
> m.hexdigest()
> '031edd7d41651593c5fe5c006fa5752b37fddff7bc4e843aa6af0c950f4b9406'
> ```

Таким образом можно написать код так:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(bytes([160])) # 160 или int('10100000', 2)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

и мы получим то что требовалось:

```
c19a797fa1fd590cd2e5b42d1cf5f246e29b91684e2f87404b81dc345c7a56a0
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, сид фразы получаются валидными. Для чисел более 225 нужен такой код: `hash=sha256()
hash.update(bytes([int(b[i-8:i], 2) for i in range(8, len(b)+1, 8) ]))` где b-двоичное число, длина которого кратна 8 (т.е весит целое кол-во бит)